# Why am i not getting an input to type a string? (i want to replace all digits with an underscore _ )

Tags: python, string, input

```
string = str(input("Input a string? "))
print(string)

for isdigit in string:
    str.replace(isdigit, "_")
```

Comment: Is it your real code? It seems pseudo...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What do you mean by "not getting an input"? The first line of your code prompts for input. I just ran it and it works fine, though there's an error later in the program. Please [edit] to clarify. Also, for debugging help, it's best to provide a [mre].

Comment: @Word It's Python, lol :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be misunderstanding how `isdigit` and `replace` work.  `isdigit` is a string method that returns `True` is the string is a digit or `False` if it is not.  Note, you are not actually using `isdigit` the method, you are using the name as a variable.  `replace` replaces one sub-string with another sub-string in a string, but does not handle abstract sub-strings like "strings-that-are-digits."  Here are a couple of ways to accomplish what you have in mind:

Example #1:

```
test_string = "this 1 is a 2 test 3 with4 a num5ber of dig6its in it."

converted_string = ""
for char in test_string:
    converted_string += "_" if char.isdigit() else char

print(converted_string)
```

Output:

```
this _ is a _ test _ with_ a num_ber of dig_its in it.
```

Example #2:

```
import re

test_string = "this 1 is a 2 test 3 with4 a num5ber of dig6its in it."

converted_string = re.sub("\d", "_", test_string)

print(converted_string)
```

Output:

```
this _ is a _ test _ with_ a num_ber of dig_its in it.
```